# Choosing $k$ objects from $n$ groups, at least one for each group ($k>n$)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm struggling to come up with the method to find the number of ways to take $k$ objects from $n$ groups which at least one object from each group is taken and order matters.

More specifically, I'm trying to order $8$ digits from the digit pool of $5-10$ ($6$ digits) and each digit must appear at least once and the order matters, e.g. $5,6,7,8,9,10,5,5$ is fine and different from $5,5,6,7,5,8,9,10$ which is also acceptable.

I'd like to know the method of finding this, something like a generating function or other combinatorics calculation and why it actually true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to consider the following different sets of digits

- $ \{5,6,7,8,9,10,\color{red}{5,5}\},\{5,6,7,8,9,10,\color{red}{5,6}\},...,\{5,6,7,8,9,10,\color{red}{10,10}\}$

which are $21$ ($6$ with one triple of repeated digits and $15$ with $2$ pairs of repeated digits) and we can permutate each one taking into account the repeated digits, therefore the number of different groups is

$$\frac{15\cdot 8!}{2!2!}+\frac{6\cdot 8!}{3!}=191\,520$$

Comment: no, we need to pick 8 digits from 6 pools, 10,5,6,7,8,9,8,10 is also acceptable and the order of those matters see the Q

Comment: This might have been correct if I was talking about sets, the order does matter so this is incorrect.

Comment: @Ofek.T. Yes you are right, what about the latter solution?

Comment: This the correct but I didn't get the calculation there, can you explain why each number is there (8! is n of course, and 15 and 6 are the number of sets, but the others?)

Comment: @Ofek.T. We have 21 different sets to be considered, among them 6 have 2 equal pairs such as $\{5,6,7,8,9,10,\color{red}{5,6}\}$ and $15 $have one triple, therefore we need to divide $6*8!$ by $(2!*2!)$ and $15*8!$ by $3!$ to not overcount for the triple and pairs of identical digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an induction on $n$. For $n=1$ it's easy. If you know the number (call it $\phi(r)$) for all $r<n$. Then, if I'm not mistaken,

$$\phi(n) = \psi(n) - \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r}\phi(r)$$

with $\psi(n)$ the number of ways to choose $k$ from $n$ groups without the imposed restriction.

Comment: The formula just substracts all choices where one or more groups are missed out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in generating functions, here is an exponential generating function approach.  Let $a_r$ be the number of strings of length $r$ with characters taken from a six-character alphabet, with each character used at least once.  We define the exponential generating function of $a_r$ by
$$f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_r}{r!} x^r$$

The exponential generating function for the number of occurrences of any single character is
$$x + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \dots = e^x-1$$
since the character must appear at least once, so 
$$f(x) = (e^x-1)^6$$
The generating function is interesting in its own right, but if you want a formula for $a_r$ you might start by expanding $(e^x-1)^6$ by the Binomial Theorem, with the result
$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^6 \binom{6}{j} e^{jx} (-1)^{6-j} $$
So
$$\begin{align}
a_r &= r!\; [x^r] f(x) \\
&= r! \; \sum_{j=0}^6 \binom{6}{j} (-1)^{6-j} [x^r] e^{jx} \\
&=r! \; \sum_{j=0}^6 \binom{6}{j} (-1)^{6-j} \frac{j^r}{r!} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^6 \binom{6}{j} (-1)^{6-j} j^r
\end{align}$$
where $[x^r]$ is the "coefficient of $x^r$" operator.